# Bayesian multiple regression

Tags: statistics, regression, mathematical-modeling, bayesian

I have a response variable and 6 possible covariates, and I have to fit a model using Bayesian statistics. I've looked for resources, but I'm struggling to find any where someone has shown an example of creating a Bayesian model (preferably using R) so that I can learn how to do it.

Can anyone point me towards some good resources for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for rstanarm package in R. In particular stan_lm() function. The sintaxis of this function is the same as base 'lm()', base 'summary' and broom package methods also work with stan_reg objects.